# Need help reading data from input files and displaying it

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, input

I'm in an intro comp sci class in college(I'm fairly new to programming as a whole) and for a project we were told to do below 
1. Design and write a program to read students’ scores from an input file, compute their letter grade 
and display their name and letter grade. Each line of text in the input file will have all the information 
about a single student - first and last name followed by 5 assignment scores, 5 quiz scores and 2 exam 
scores. All information fields are separated by spaces. The assignments are scored out of 100, the 
quizzes out of 20 and the exams out of 100. Here is some sample input:
Steve Smith 100 70 80 55 90 15 20 18 17 12 78 84

My problem is it is treating all of the input as the same thing so I'm unable to pull specific parts of the above example out and compute the students grade, here is my code so far

```
def file():
  myfile = pickAFile()
  print myfile
  file = open(myfile,"rt")
  contents = file.readlines()
  list = [contents]
  print list[0]
```

but it keeps printing out the entire sample input instead of just the first word and I don't know why please help if possible I'm using JES

Comment: Maybe you mean `list = [item for item in contents.split(" ")`?

Comment: `list = [contents]` puts `contents` (a list of lines) into a list. You're then printing out the first and only element of that list, which is a list of all of the lines in the file. If you change this to `list = contents`, you'll be printing the first line only.

Comment: I've tried that and I still get the entire sample input, when I need to be able to pick out individual things from it such as just printing Steve or only printing the numbers

Comment: How can I make every part of the sample input a different element in the same list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readlines` is already a `list` so you are putting a list inside a list with `list =[contents]`, use:

```
list = contents
print list[0]
```

Or simply:

```
print file.readlines()[0]
```

Also better to avoid using `list` as a variable name  as it shadows the builtin `list`.

```
def file():
  myfile = pickAFile()
  with open(myfile) as f: # with closes your files automatically 
       contents = f.readlines()  # creates a list 
       print contents[0] # print first element
```

If you want to split each line into  lists with the lines split into single words replace `contents = f.readlines()` with:

```
contents = [x.split() for x in f] # if words are separated by whitespace

In [17]: s= "Steve Smith 100 70 80 55 90 15 20 18 17 12 78 84"
In [18]: s.split()
Out[18]: 
['Steve',
 'Smith',
 '100',
 '70',
 '80',
 '55',
 '90',
 '15',
 '20',
 '18',
 '17',
 '12',
 '78',
 '84']
```

Or use `f.read().split()` to makes a single list

As commented the input is always in the same format so to make the digits into ints:

```
s = "Steve Smith 100 70 80 55 90 15 20 18 17 12 78 84"
spl = s.split()
spl[2:] = map(int,spl[2:])
print(spl)
['Steve', 'Smith', 100, 70, 80, 55, 90, 15, 20, 18, 17, 12, 78, 84]
```

Comment: JES doesnt appear to recognize "with" and the other suggestions still wont allow me to print individual elements from the input file which contains: Steve Smith 100 70 80 55 90 15 20 18 17 12 78 84

Comment: sorry, I missed the JES part I have never used it but all the above is valid python syntax, does `file.read().split()` work in your own code? It should split as above

Comment: It's fine, and no file.read().split() isn't working I'm still getting the full sample input, here is the full description of the assignment for clarity

Comment: 1. Design and write a program to read students’ scores from an input file, compute their letter grade 
and display their name and letter grade. Each line of text in the input file will have all the information 
about a single student - first and last name followed by 5 assignment scores, 5 quiz scores and 2 exam 
scores. All information fields are separated by spaces. The assignments are scored out of 100, the 
quizzes out of 20 and the exams out of 100. Here is some sample input:
Steve Smith 100 70 80 55 90 15 20 18 17 12 78 84

Comment: we then need to do some basic calculations and print out a grade, my problem is I don't know how to alter each element of the list so I don't know how to display the students name or calculate there grade because I can't access the individual elements but besides that I'm pretty confident

Comment: are the words separated by spaces or commas?

Comment: JES and python have almost identical syntax except python has a bit more in terms of things like "with"

Comment: they are separated by spaces

Comment: in your code when you `print file.read()`  what does it look like?

Comment: It just gives me the entire sample input: Steve Smith 100 70 80 55 90 15 20 18 17 12 78 84

Comment: A step in the right direction, it split all of the sample input into separate elements which I can now manipulate, do you know how I can turn the numbers into integers so that when I add them or subtract them etc. It will actually perform the arithmetic instead of just printing out the two elements?

Comment: Yes the format is consistent and will always be first name last name followed by 12 grades

Answer (score 1):

See this helps you:

```py
with open("student_data.txt") as f:
   lines = [x.split() for x in f]

for line in lines:
   print line
   print "Full Name: ", " ".join(line[:2])
   print "Assignment Scores: ", ", ".join(line[2:7])
   print "Quiz Scores: ", ", ".join(line[7:9])
   print "Exam Scores: ", ", ".join(line[9:])

   print (sum([int(x) for x in line[2:7]])/5 + sum([int(x) for x in line[7:9]])/2 + sum([int(x) for x in line[9:]])/5)/3
```

I'm not sure how the average / grade that you want to calculate, but I believe that you can sort it out.